# run dpkg --get-selections | grep -i apache on ubuntu 18.04 not showing apache is installed or not

Tags: dpkg

while I run "dpkg --get-selections | grep -i apache" on ubuntu 18.04 , it is not showing any package of apache, but when type "apt install apache" on terminal and press tab, it's showing many apache options, please explain what i am doing worng ?

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections` without a pattern forces not-installed packages to NOT be shown (taken from `man dpkg`)  - is your issue that you want to display not-installed? using an option that excludes them?   You didn't say what you were after with your command.

Comment: Try `dpkg -l | grep -i apache` instead.

Comment: @guiverc:- dpkg should list installed package as it is listing python installed packages, while trying to install apache :- 'apt install apache' it show many possibilities, got to know that its just showing options based on repository not the installed options. am i right

Answer (score 0):

The results of `sudo apt install apache` followed by pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to show autocomplete suggestions are as follows:

```
apache2                  apache2-doc              apachedex
apache2-bin              apache2-ssl-dev          apacheds
apache2-data             apache2-suexec-custom    apachetop
apache2-dbg              apache2-suexec-pristine  
apache2-dev              apache2-utils
```

In order to determine which apache package to install run the following command:

```
apt-cache show apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-dbg apache2-dev apache2-doc apache2-ssl-dev apache2-suexec-custom apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-utils apachedex apacheds apachetop
```

`apt-cache show` shows information about packages including the package's description and dependencies. The description of the apache2 package is:

```
Description-en: Apache HTTP Server
```

This shows that apache2 is the package that you need to install. Installing apache2 will also install some of the other listed apache packages as its dependencies.

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

As a further check run the following command to show whether or not Apache HTTP Server is installed.

```
apt policy apache2
```